# plist controller class

Tags: iphone, ios, plist, nsobject

I am creating a plist controller class that dose things like takes my plist saves it to the document root saves all the values in my plist to variables that will be used for checking my connection responses.

also I do things like saving new values when needed.

the issue I am having however is that I want to access this one class from many classes but if I initialize it in one class and then another I am creating two objects am I not?

so my question is whats the best way for handling a class that has to be accessed from a couple of different classes?

Comment: Please search for the singleton pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you using these other classes?  If they are view controllers then creating an instance in each is perfectly fine.

If they are objects created within the same view controller, try having your objects take your object as function input.  That way you can create one instance of that object and share it with all your other objects.  Here is an example:

```
-(void)myFunction:(plistControlClass *)myPlistController{

}
```